# Entering formula into Latex - urgent issue

Tags: mathematics

Good evening everyone,
would anyone please help me out with transferring this screenshot into LaTex? It would be optimal, to have the equation in the same line. I have to hand it in within the next few hours and I am not very experienced in using the required math package. It would be of great help to me. Please find the screenshot attached. Thanks a lot!

Best regards,
Michael
[image]

Comment: We generally frown on "do this for me" that don't show any work.  It would greatly help us if you showed what you've already tried, and explained why that is deficient.  (I also find "urgent" to be offputting - it's not our problem that you waited this long - but that may just be me.)  And you've gotten an answer, so maybe this comment if for naught.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is (the `\otherbeta` command is specific to the `fourier` font, to have an upright lowercase Greek letter in maths):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} %% differential symbol for integrals

\begin{document}

\[ U(1,\otherbeta) = \int_{1-p}^p \max\nolimits_B\bigl\{pu\bigl(w + 1-P)B\bigr) + (1-p)u(w-PB)\bigr\}\dd M_{\otherbeta}(P) \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're right. I overlooked these details.